# How to find a variable which has a certain string?

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a script that checks all variables starting with 'var' for a certain string. I have three variables in the code below and I want it to find the string `code` and output the name of the variable that contains it.

```
set var1=hi
set var2=code
set var3=bye

:: variable checker here

echo Variable %variable% has the string 'code' in it.
```

In the example above, the output should be `var2`, but I haven't the slightest clue how to check the variables for the string.

Comment: Could this help you, `@For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set var 2^>NUL^|Find /I "code"')Do @Echo Variable %%A has the string 'code' in it.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my comment as an answer complete with `Rem`arks to show how it works:

```bat
@Echo Off
Rem Undefine any variables whose names begin with Var
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set Var 2^>NUL')Do Set "%%A="

Rem Define some new variables whose names begin with Var
Set "Var1=Some string"
Set "Var2=A code string"
Set "Var3=Another string with code in it"
Set "Var4=345678"

Rem Show all variables whose names begin with Var and their values
Set Var 2>NUL

Rem Check for any variable whose names begin with Var and has a value with the string 'code' in it
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set Var 2^>NUL^|Find "code"')Do Echo Variable %%A has the string 'code' in it.

Rem Pause the script to see the output
Pause
```

You could of course use the `/I` option with `Find` to ignore case when searching for the required string.

If you wanted to see if the value case insensitively matches `code` you could change the second `For` loop to:

```bat
For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%A In ('Set Var 2^>NUL')Do If /I "%%B"=="code" Echo Variable %%A has the string value 'code'.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really straight forward, assuming the variable should contain `code` in any form:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%i in ('set ^|findstr "code" ^|findstr "var"') do echo %%i has code in it as %%j
```

or if case is not important:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%i in ('set ^|findstr /i "code" ^|findstr /i "var"') do echo %%i has code in it as %%j
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to find the variable(s) with a certain value:

```cmd
2> nul set VAR | findstr /X /I /C:"[^=][^=]*=code"
```

To process the result use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html):

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1* delims== eol==" %%V in ('
    2^> nul set VAR ^| findstr /X /I /C:"[^=][^=]*=code"
') do echo Variable %%V is set to %%W.
```

Remove `/I` in case you want to do a case-sensitive comparison.

If you do not want the whole value to match, replace `/X` by `/B` to match the beginning or by `/E` to match the end, or remove `/X` to match anywhere.

If a value begins with (an) `=`-sign(s) it/they will be missing in the output.